# Codeigniter htaccess and routes files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my htaccess and routes files. I want configure my default_controller.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'fr/index';
```

And I want to use URL rewritting. Remove 'index.php' in my URLs with htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/page=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets/|robots.txt) 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

When one works, the other doesn't work.

Have you an idea to configure my htaccess for remove 'index.php' and add a default_controller to routes.php ?

My controllers are in a subfolder to application/controllers/subfolder/myControllers.php

Thanks for yours answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is .htaccess configuration I'm using for myself. It will remove index.php and add www at the begining of the domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

also it works with default controller in sub-folder for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a problem at line 12. What flag ? I have a shared hosting at OVH. On localhost, I don't have problem with my configuration but not on shared hosting.

Comment: You should check your mod-rewrite configuration on your server.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. Your htaccess doesn't work for my application on my shared hosting. I found the solution

Comment: you should answer your own question with the solution you find.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. I don't know why but this htaccess run correctly :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I try near 30 differents htaccess.